# Testing for extinction using the binomial distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, ecology

I'm using quadrat sampling to determine whether a species of plant is present in a given area - my end goal is to work out how many quadrats need to be checked without finding anything before I can safely say that the plant is not present.

**Preamble**

- In areas where the plant is present, it occurs with a density of `p` plants/m<sup>2</sup>.
- Let `ρ` be the actual density of the plant in the area that I am checking.
- If I use quadrats of size 1m<sup>2</sup>, the probability of finding a plant in any given quadrat is `ρ`.
- If I check a random sample of `n` such quadrats, the total number of plants found `X` should follow a `Binomial(n,ρ)` distribution.

**Hypothesis test**

H<sub>0</sub>: `ρ=p`

H<sub>1</sub>: `ρ=0`

**If find zero plants in my `n` quadrats, can I reject H<sub>0</sub> at the 1% significance level?**

- Under H<sub>0</sub> `X~Binomial(n,p)` so the probability of finding
  zero plants (or less)  is:

  $\mathbb{P}(X\leq0)=\mathbb{P}(X=0)=(1-p)^n $
- So I should reject H<sub>0</sub> if $(1-p)^n < 0.01$

**How many quadrats do I have to check without finding anything before can I reject H<sub>0</sub> at the 1% significance level?**

H<sub>0</sub> will be rejected when:

$\begin{aligned} (1-p)^n &< 0.01 \\ \log(1-p)^n &< \log(0.01) \\ n\log(1-p) &< \log(0.01) \\ n &> \frac{\log(0.01)}{\log(1-p)} \end{aligned}$

So I need to check $1+\frac{\log(0.01)}{\log(1-p)}$ quadrats without finding anything before I can reject H<sub>0</sub>.

**Questions**

1. I think there's something wrong with my reasoning as regards to probability of finding a plant in any given quadrat:

   - Does the probability depend on the size of the quadrat?
   - Does the probability depend on the size of the plant in relation to the quadrat?
2. I've never done a hypothesis test where H<sub>1</sub> is a specific alternative (i.e. `ρ=0`) - it's normally something like H<sub>0</sub>: `ρ=x`, H<sub>1</sub>: `ρ<x`. Does the hypothesis test still work as normal?

Comment: "safely say that the plant is not present." How safe? 100%?

Comment: @user158565 You'll see I've specified a significance level of 1% later on, which is the probability of a Type I error - rejecting the null hypothesis when it is in fact true, or in this case "Saying that the plant is not present in the area when it actually is".

Comment: Your analysis is highly reliant on an assumption that plant-locations are independent of each other. At first glance, I'd find that a highly dubious assumption given that we know a little about how plants make more plants. What's a good basis on which to treat them as independent?

Comment: I think it long time but did not get the answer. Your p value (1-$\rho)^n$ depends on your null hypothesis. BTW, your $p$ and $\rho$ are messed up together.